Domination implies non-pseudo-effectiveness?
Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a projective morphism between smooth varieties and $D\subset X$ an $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier divisor. We say $D$ is $f$-pseudo-effective if $D+A$ is $f$-big for any $f$-ample $\mathbb{R}$-divisor $A$ on $X$.
Now assume that $E$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier divisor on $X$ which dominates $Y$. Is it true that $E$ is not $f$-pseudo-effective?

consider the case that E is effective and Y is a point
